# How can i set count at Mailchimp Marketink API with PHP listing campaigns

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
require_once '/home/Javi/mailchimp-marketing-php/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();
$client->setConfig(['apiKey' => 'APIKEY','server' => 'PREFIX']);

$response = $client->campaigns->list();
print_r($response);
```

Default value for $client->campaigns->list(); is 10, i need to change it, i've tried different ways but always list me only 10 elements.

Anyone who works with mailchimp marketing API could help me with that issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with the same thing, but was able to find a workaround that is perhaps not best practice, but at least gives you the desired outcome.

Have a look at the sourcecode here:
https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php/blob/master/lib/Api/CampaignsApi.php

search for  "public function list", which just calls another function called "listWithHttpInfo()".

this functions takes a lot of arguments, and when I passed in values for all of them in the right order, the function returned my desired result.

listWithHttpInfo($fields, $exclude_fields, $count, $offset, $type, $status, $before_send_time, $since_send_time, $before_create_time, $since_create_time, $list_id, $folder_id, $member_id, $sort_field, $sort_dir);

try calling:

```
$client->campaigns->listWithHttpInfo(null, null, '50', '0', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Where '50' is the count parameter.
And see if that is what you are looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just needed the same thing and after some testing I solved it as indicated below.

For interests of categories:

```
$response = $mailchimp->lists->listInterestCategoryInterests({audience_id}, {caterogy_interest_id}, null, null, {count}, {offset});
```

For campaigns:

```
$response = $mailchimp->campaigns->list(null, null, {count}, {offset});
```

I hope it helps others too.

Ciauz!